# Why can't I change the value of this nonconstant variable?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a huge library that I am trying to understand and I ran into a problem while doing some unit tests (boost): memory access violation no mapping at false address.

To explain the relevant parts of their structure and what I try to do, imagine this:

```
struct A {int x;}
class B { public: A *a; A(something_else) { some_function;} }
```

In my main file, I initialize an A object and print A.a->x (and I get 0). If I write A.a->x=0, no problem. If I try to modify the value in any way, I get the said error... What is going on? Also, I don't want to modify their code, but I really need to increment that x.

Comment: struct A { int x; } <~ needs ; at the end

Comment: The member variable `a` doesn't appear to be initialized to anything - it needs to point at some memory that is valid to use to store an int...

Comment: Show real code. Reduce it to the smallest example you can come up with that compiles and runs and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: That "some_function" makes use of other functions that are in over 3 source files and that all have a length of tens of rows... And I want to use their library, not to understand it or modify it. I just want to know what could possibly cause the problem?

Comment: You said: "If I write A.a->x=0, no problem. If I try to modify the value in any way, I get the said error..." - what is that supposed to mean??? `A.a->x=0` is an attempt to modify `x`. And you said it gives you "no problem". Yet in the very next sentence you say that any attempt to modify `x` gives you an error. This is self contradictory. So, what is it: "no problem" or "gives error"???

Answer (score 2):

According to your statements it looks like the pointer isn't initialized before it's usage.

```
A* a; // This pointer points to nothing ... meaning a == NULL / 0

int b = a->x; // ERROR! Segmentation fault!

a = new A;

int c = a->x; // Undefined

a->x = 5;

int d = a->x; // 5


/* ... */

delete a;
```

```
/* Library */

struct Bar
{
    int a;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Bar* pBar;
    Foo(){ }
    ~Foo()
    {
        delete pBar; // If it's null, nothing will happen
    }
};


/* main.cpp */

Foo foo();
foo.pBar = new Bar;

foo.pBar->a = 5; // 5
```

a has nothing to do with pBar

```
pBar->a = 5;
```

translates to

```
*(pBar).a = 5;
```

Comment: The thing is that I want to use their library, not to modify it, and I find it hard to believe that there is something wrong with their code. I just need to know what could possibly cause the error.

Comment: It's not about the definition, it's about how to properly use it. **Bjarne** could make a lib containing a public pointer. That doesn't mean that the pointer would be magically initialized. It's your job to do that.